# How to get the Latest record created date in salesforce?

Tags: apex, formula, date

I have a field called **"Date"**  on custom object **"TestData__c"**.

If I create a record today I need to display today date.If I create a record tomorrow I need to display Tomorrow date.How Can I achieve this.

How to make **Date**  field as dynamic

Example

Records like

Name : "Test1"  date : "17/08/2019" 
Name : "Test2   date" : "18/08/2019"
Nmae : "Test3   date" : "19/08/2019"

Anyone help me on this requirement.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `CreatedDate` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT MAX(CreatedDate) FROM TestData__c
```

or similar. Take a look at [aggregate functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Date from the CreatedDate field by creating a formula field with below formula

```
DATEVALUE( CreatedDate )
```

Alternatively, you can also create a Date field and populate it in Before Insert trigger with below code

```
TestData__c.Date__c = System.Today();
```

This will help to keep the Date field dynamic.

However, this is not at all required because you can get this information dynamically from CreatedDate field and if you require the data in reports its already avaliable. If you require this data while processing then you can write something like

```
Date myDate = TestData__c.Date__c.date(); // to return Date in user's timezone
```

or

```
Date myDate = TestData__c.Date__c.dateGMT(); // to return Date in GMT
```